# Installing chrome extension from NSIS installer?

Tags: google-chrome, installation, google-chrome-extension, nsis

I have an application that also has a firefox and chrome extension. I am using NSIS for the installer, now I want the installer to have checkboxs asking if the user want to install the extension for his browser.

To install the firefox extension it's easy I just copy the extension files to PROGRAMFILES\Mozilla Firefox\extensions{GUID}, but I couldn't find a way I could do it for chrome (from the NSIS installer).

**Does someone knows how to achieve this?**

---

**Update:**

[External Extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions)

Thanks what I needed. (I couldn't answer my own question yet because I have to wait 8 hours for not having 100 rep)

Comment: can you show the example code to get this working in NSIS? thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
!define PRODUCT_VERSION "1.0.0"
!define CRXNAME "extension.crx"
!define CRXID "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"

SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
File "${CRXNAME}"  
WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Google\Chrome\Extensions\${CRXID}" "path" "$INSTDIR\${CRXNAME}"
WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Google\Chrome\Extensions\${CRXID}" "version"     "${PRODUCT_VERSION}"
WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Wow6432Node\Google\Chrome\Extensions\${CRXID}" "path" "$INSTDIR\${CRXNAME}"
WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Wow6432Node\Google\Chrome\Extensions\${CRXID}" "version" "${PRODUCT_VERSION}"
```

Comment: I'm having issues with these registry entries. I can't see them in regedit. It looks like another extension used the HKEY_CURRENT_USER. Under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE there is SOFTWARE, not Software. Should that matter? Should I be able to see these entries in regedit at all?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could think of is to open Chrome for the user at the specific URL where the extension is located. Of course some user instructions beforehand. 
A more evil way would be to do the SendKey events for the user. Depends how much "dancing with the devil" you are up for ;)

Comment: Well the app is not for big distribution, only for internal use and maybe 50 more people so I will consider your idea. I though there was an easier way anyway, like with firefox you have global extensions, registry installs, etc.