# Windows installer for chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have just created an extension that is to be installed on chrome for video chat. I would like to bundle it with the software that I am providing. How can I create an installer that allows me to do this.

The application is written in java and the chrome extension in the html, js, css code. I also have no problem in writing the code in vb but I just cant find any links where they have information on this.

Comment: The chrome extension, after packaging should be a single `.crx` archive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to install a Chrome extension via other software, [this might help](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions.html).

However, I believe that the user now has to approve the installation under the Wrench icon.

Comment: I have seen applications such as skype extension being installed. How does it manage that.

Comment: You mean Skype installing the Skype extension in Chrome? [see the chrome docs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions.html)

Comment: Yes, I did. However, what I would like to know is how can I bundle it into an installer. How can I write an installer for this. I have completed my application and chrome extension, however I do not know how I can create it into an .exe file that can show the user the options to install my program. How do people create installers for programs. I have a program in java and I also have one in vb.net. How can I create an installation executable for them while bundling the chrome extension with them. That is what I asked in the question but I think it didn't make much sense.

Comment: oh, you mean how to create an installer file... that's actually kind of annoying to do, but [Wikipedia has a list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software), though  there's [an SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8571573/689161) on how to do that with [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page).

Comment: hope it helped - sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 3):

You need create exe(or vb script) as part of your installer which will create in windows registry record for your extension:

Find or create the following key in the registry:

```
32-bit Windows: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Google\Chrome\Extensions
64-bit Windows: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Google\Chrome\Extensions
```

Create a new key (folder) under the Extensions key with the same name as the ID of your extension (for example, aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbcccccccccc).

In your extension key, create a property, "update_url", and set it to the value: "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx" (this points to your extension's crx in the Chrome Web Store):

```
{
  "update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx"
}
```

Launch the browser and go to `chrome://extensions`; you should see the extension listed.

More info can be found [in official docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions#registry)

Comment: Important point: the user will still have to manually confirm that they want that extension when Chrome is launched.

Comment: Actually not, I've just tested it and user just get notification aboout that new notification was installed. Confirmation will appears only if you use inline installation.

Comment: Have you ever installed that extension ID before on that profile? The user acceptance might be cached.

Comment: Good point. Yes, before I've installed extension in developer mode and from web store. Can you help, where I can clear this cache to check the case?

Comment: No idea, but you can just make a new webstore item to confirm. Or create a new Chrome profile.

Comment: Also, Developer Mode enabled _may_ be a factor. All in all, just try a new Chrome profile.